# Add a option group label to drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-select

I am creating a drop down for users like -

```
  = f.association :user,  :collection => current_user.company.users.order('first_name'),
                      :include_blank => "Select a approver",
                      :label => false,
```

It creates a drop down what i want.
Now i want to add one label before all users which will be not selectable

I want m drop to look like

```
label field   
all users list goes after label
```

This label field will be non selectable i.e. user cannot select this label.
any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You can add an option manually like this:

```
:collection => { "My new label" => ""}.merge(current_user.company.users.order('first_name'))
```

You probably want to extract this into a helper method, but i'll leave that up to you.

The new option is now associated with an empty value, so you could prevent the selection of this option with a validation in your model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveReceord::Base
  validates :user, :presence => true

  # ...
end
```

Now for the disabling of specific options, you can add an option `:disabled => [...]` to select helpers, that will add the [HTML `disabled` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp) to the select options you specify:

```
= f.association :user,
    :collection => :collection => { "My new label" => ""}.merge(current_user.company.users.order('first_name')),
    :include_blank => "Select a approver",
    :label => false,
    :disabled => [""]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. But this is also not working, it is showing below error 

    can't convert ActiveRecord::Relation into Hash

Comment: Thanks again... I'm using disabled option. but what i want is to add a non selecting label to the drop down

Comment: And though it works, it is going to add one blank value option field to drop down like :include_blank

Comment: Sorry i do not fully understad what you mean by "non selecting label". Can you please update your answer with more detail on how the drop down list should look like, maybe with an examle list?

Comment: I understand that you actually want to create an HTML `<label>` element, that will not highlight the dropdown list when it is clicked. Why would you want that? It is absolutely bad practice.

Comment: Hmmm yes, but i want to implement it... Do you know any solution for this

Comment: Well you could just add a label tag in plain html.

Comment: Thanks i tried adding label in plain html but it is giving an error. will  you please update how could i add it